# p:fileUpload not working after rendered by p:ajax

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I´m getting confused why the component `p:fileUpload` doesn´t call the `fileUploadListener` once the component is shown by the `p:ajax`. If I put it outside the `panelGrid`s or even remove them, works just fine.

What isn´t working:

```
<div class="pure-control-group"> 
    <label for="mostraNoIndex">Slideshow</label>
    <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{destaqueCadastrarBean.d.apareceNoSlide}">
        <p:ajax event="change" update="upload"></p:ajax>
    </p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
</div>                                      

<h:panelGrid id="upload">
    <h:panelGrid rendered="#{destaqueCadastrarBean.d.apareceNoSlide}">
        <div class="pure-control-group"> 
            <label for="mostraNoIndex">Imagem</label>
            <p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{destaqueCadastrarBean.handleFileUpload}" mode="advanced" dragDropSupport="true" sizeLimit="100000000000" fileLimit="1" allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/" />                                    
        </div>
   </h:panelGrid>
</h:panelGrid>
```

What works:

```
<div class="pure-control-group"> 
    <label for="mostraNoIndex">Slideshow</label>
    <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{destaqueCadastrarBean.d.apareceNoSlide}">
    </p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
</div>  

<div class="pure-control-group"> 
    <label for="mostraNoIndex">Imagem</label>
    <h:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{destaqueCadastrarBean.handleFileUpload}" mode="advanced" dragDropSupport="true" sizeLimit="100000000000" fileLimit="1" allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/" />                                    
</div>
```

Comment: I think the reference `upload` is not right here. Where is your form ?

Comment: The upload reference is right, cause when the p:selectBooleanCheckbox is pressed/clicked the panelGrid comes up correctly. I took the form out just to keep it clean, should I post it? A little big though.

Comment: And `<p:fileUpload>` instead of `<h:fileUpload>` ?

Comment: It is indeed <p:fileUpload>. Sorry, copy/paste

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found out a solution for it. The bean being called was `RequestScoped`, changed it to `ViewScoped`. I guess cause the bean was requested when the form loaded and p:fileUpload can only appears after the creation of the bean, the component couldn´t reach the bean. With view scope the bean is available for components that comes afterward. If someone has a more technical and clear explanation I would like to understand better.